# Foreach not hitting last item

Tags: java, foreach

I have a `foreach` that is suppose to go through and `arraylist` and perform an action every time an item changes.

So it for something like:

```
ID | Request
1  |   z
2  |   e
```

it sends an email to `1` saying "You have 1 request". Then an email to `2` "You have 1 request" and so on.

My loop doesn't address the last item when there's only 2 items in the list and I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out the elegant way to address it.

```
Integer managerId = null;
Integer previousManagerId = null;
if(requests != null && requests.size() > 0){
        for(Request request : requests){
            managerId = request.getId();

            if((!managerId.equals(previousId) && previousId != null)){
                e.sendEmail(previousId, numReq.toString());
                numReq = 0;
            }
            numReq++;

            previousId = managerId;

        }
        //Suppose to address the last item. Fails when size == 2
        if((!managerId.equals(previousId) && previousId != null)){
            eusendEmail(previousId, numReq.toString());
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by fails? Is there an error?

Comment: Which version of Java? If Java8, you can use streams and get rid of lot of noise around your code.

Comment: @Atri No it treats the arraylist as size ==1 and skips the last one entirely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last statement of the loop ensures that `previousId` is always equal to `managerId` after the loop ends, so it can never go into the `if`.

I think you always want to send the last email because you know there was at least one request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the previousId outside the for each because it will delet this value every time it goes trough the next object ;)

But why are you doing the first if? Wouldn't the foreach do that anyway?

How if you try like this:

```
    String managerId = "";
    for(Request request : requests){
        managerId = request.getId();

        if(!managerId.equals(previousId)){
            request.sendEmail(previousId, numReq.toString());
            numReq = 0;
        }
        numReq++;
    }
```

Comment: your if statement consider first if the arraylist isn't empty and then you ensure again if it is not empty? because if the arraylist size is bigger than 0 it is not empty?! And i thought the foreach handle this issue itself if the arraylist would be empty there would be no loop and no error as well?!

Comment: I'm already doing that. `managerId = request.getId();` wouldn't work if it wasn't initialized first.